# What does symbol ¤ means in URL?

Tags: url, thymeleaf

I have a link:

```
 /manager_admin/all_orders_manager?pageNo=1&amp;sortField=date&amp;sortDir=asc&amp;date=null&amp;time=null&amp;term=null&amp;seller=null&amp;orderType=null&amp;platform=null&amp;dateTo=null&amp;timeTo=null&amp;isMoney=false&amp;payment=null¤cyAbbr=USD"
```

Thymeleaf link looks like:

```
                    <a th:href = "@{'/manager_admin/all_orders_manager?pageNo=' + ${currentPage} + '&sortField=date&sortDir=' + ${reverseSortDir}
                     + '&date=' + ${date} + '&time=' + ${time} + '&term=' + ${term} + '&seller=' + ${seller} + '&orderType=' + ${orderType}
                      + '&platform=' + ${platform} + '&dateTo=' + ${dateTo} + '&timeTo=' + ${timeTo} + '&isMoney=' + ${isMoney} + '&payment=' + ${payment}}">
```

I don't understand why this symbol (¤) appears. I checked parentheses and backend code works fine. When I erase at least one parameter ¤ disappears.

Comment: This doesn't look valid.  Certainly, such characters are out of spec for URI, although maybe less-strict systems will allow it to pass.  It looks to me like this symbol should be another `&amp;`

Comment: It should be another &amp but it also replaces the part of the last parameter "currencyAbbr". It's just ¤cyAbbr now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign ¤ is used for currency. Because my parameter name was "currencyAbbr", it was translated to ¤cyAbbr automatically.

Comment: Translated by what?   Why just in place of "curren" leaving the "cy"?